# Nginx extract file extension from $uri and pass it to map and location

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm trying to replace Content-Type header based on file extension (end of $uri).

I found working solution, but it consists of many rules, each rule for one file extension.

```
location ~ /middle/path/.*\.(html)$ {
  proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
  add_header Content-Type 'text/html';
}
```

So I want to make smaller rule by extracting file extension and mapping it to right content-type.
`$uri` looks like `/middle/path/index.html` and I expect `$file_extension` to be `.html`, so `$new_content_type` will be `'text/html'`.

```
map $uri $file_extension {
  default "extension not found...";
  ~\.[0-9a-z]+$ $1;
}

map $file_extension $new_content_type {
  default "content type not found...";
  .css 'text/css';
  .csv 'text/csv';
  .html 'text/html';
  .ico 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon';
  .js 'text/javascript';
  .jpg 'image/jpeg';
  .jpeg 'image/jpeg';
  .json 'application/json';
  .md 'text/markdown';
  .png 'image/png';
  .txt 'text/plain';
}

    
location ~ /middle/path/.*\.(html|txt|md|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
  proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
  add_header x-file-extension "$file_extension"; # header missing from response
  add_header x-new-content-type "$new_content_type"; # "content type not found..."
  add_header Content-Type $new_content_type;
}
```

So I don't know how to write first map to get file extension.

Comment: You are missing any parentheses to capture `$1`. For example: `~*(\.[0-9a-z]+)$ $1;`

Comment: Yes, thank you, I realized this a short time after the question was published, but decided not to delete the question, in case someone would find an example of working with regex and Map in Nginx useful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at regex, but looks like I missed `()` to use groups, so now everything is working:

```
map $uri $file_extension {
  default "extension not found...";
  ~\.([0-9a-z]+)$ $1;
}

map $file_extension $new_content_type {
  default "content type not found...";
  css 'text/css';
  csv 'text/csv';
  html 'text/html';
  ico 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon';
  js 'text/javascript';
  jpg 'image/jpeg';
  jpeg 'image/jpeg';
  json 'application/json';
  md 'text/markdown';
  png 'image/png';
  txt 'text/plain';
}

location ~ /middle/path/.*\.(css|csv|html|ico|js|jpg|jpeg|json|md|png|txt)$ {
  proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
  add_header Content-Type $new_content_type;
}
```